# $group and timestamp $sort mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, grouping

I want to sort documents by timestamp and get distinct children name. So the expected of the query is something like;

```
[alex, elizabeth, felix, tom, sonny, ashton, sharon]
```

The collection is;

```
{ "timestamp" : 1486641003000, children: [{name: "sharon"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486645481504, children: [{name: "tom"} , {name: "alex"}]},
{ "timestamp" : 1486732863102, children: [{name: "alex"}, {name: "elizabeth"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486642403974, children: [{name: "sonny"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486641003000, children: [{name: "elizabeth"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486645481504, children: [{name: "felix"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486645481504, children: [{name: "tom"} , {name: "alex"}]},
{ "timestamp" : 1486642623178, children: [{name: "alex"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486642403974, children: [{name: "felix"}] },
{ "timestamp" : 1486641003000, children: [{name: "ashton"}] },
```

What have I done so far?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$children"},
    {$sort: {"timestamp" : -1}},
    {$group: {"_id" : "" , children: {$addToSet: "$children.name"}}}
])
```

but I think grouping overwrites the the sorting according to the timestamp. Because the result is not like what I expected;

```
{ "_id" : "", "children" : [ "ashton", "felix", "tom", "sonny", "elizabeth", "sharon", "alex" ] }
```

So how can I get lastly changed distinct children' names while sorting them by timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you will have to sort and group one more time in this case.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$children"}, 
    {$sort: { "timestamp": -1 }},
    {$group: {"_id": "$children.name", "timestamp": {$first: "$timestamp"}}},
    {$sort: { "timestamp": -1 }}, 
    {$group: {"_id": null, "children": {$push: "$_id"}}}
])
```

The result will look like the following:

```
{ "_id" : null, "children" : [ "alex", "elizabeth", "tom", "felix", "sonny", "sharon", "ashton" ] }
```

it's because "tom" and "felix" have alike timestamp, the same as "sharon" and "ashton".